# Adding a button to Wagtail Dashboard

Tags: django, wagtail

Is it possible to add a additional button(*buttons*) on the top panel as shown in the picture?

[image]

I did't find anything in Google and here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not clear on the screenshot whether you use `modeladmin` or the `snippet`s to expose this model to the user but I'll assume the former.

I don't know about a hook which allows you to add buttons directly to the header, however the template [uses blocks](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/563b8e48ef80463ff40d2a98c0266622cd755a87/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/templates/modeladmin/index.html#L25-L33) which should allow us to overwrite just this part.

We can take advantage of the [resolution order](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#overriding-templates) of the templates and create `templates/modeladmin/app-name/model-name/index.html` which will take precedence over `/modeladmin/index.html`. So given with your app called `feedler` and a model called `Entry`, create `/modeladmin/feedler/entry/index.html` with the following content:

```
{% extends "modeladmin/index.html" %}

{% block header_extra %}
    <a href="#">My New Button</a>
    {{ block.super }}{% comment %}Display the original buttons {% endcomment %}
{% endblock %}
```

Right now your button doesn't do much. To create an action which will interact with that model admin, you'll need to create some button/url/permission [helpers](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#overriding-helper-classes) and a view.

Let's say the action is exporting the objects to a CSV file. Brace yourself, there's quite a bit of code ahead.

In `/feedler/admin.py`, create the button/url/permission helpers and view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.helpers import AdminURLHelper, ButtonHelper
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import IndexView


class ExportButtonHelper(ButtonHelper):
    """
    This helper constructs all the necessary attributes to create a button.
    
    There is a lot of boilerplate just for the classnames to be right :(
    """
    
    export_button_classnames = ['icon', 'icon-download']

    def export_button(self, classnames_add=None, classnames_exclude=None):
        if classnames_add is None:
            classnames_add = []
        if classnames_exclude is None:
            classnames_exclude = []

        classnames = self.export_button_classnames + classnames_add
        cn = self.finalise_classname(classnames, classnames_exclude)
        text = _('Export {}'.format(self.verbose_name_plural.title()))

        return {
            'url': self.url_helper.get_action_url('export', query_params=self.request.GET),
            'label': text,
            'classname': cn,
            'title': text,
        }


class ExportAdminURLHelper(AdminURLHelper):
    """
    This helper constructs the different urls.
    
    This is mostly just to overwrite the default behaviour
    which consider any action other than 'create', 'choose_parent' and 'index'
    as `object specific` and will try to add the object PK to the url
    which is not what we want for the `export` option.
    
    In addition, it appends the filters to the action.
    """

    non_object_specific_actions = ('create', 'choose_parent', 'index', 'export')

    def get_action_url(self, action, *args, **kwargs):
        query_params = kwargs.pop('query_params', None)

        url_name = self.get_action_url_name(action)
        if action in self.non_object_specific_actions:
            url = reverse(url_name)
        else:
            url = reverse(url_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

        if query_params:
            url += '?{params}'.format(params=query_params.urlencode())

        return url

    def get_action_url_pattern(self, action):
        if action in self.non_object_specific_actions:
            return self._get_action_url_pattern(action)

        return self._get_object_specific_action_url_pattern(action)
        

class ExportView(IndexView):
    """
    A Class Based View which will generate 
    """
    
    def export_csv(self):
        data = self.queryset.all()
        response = ...
        return response
    
    
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.export_csv()

        
class ExportModelAdminMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin to add to your model admin which hooks the different helpers, the view
    and register the new urls.
    """

    button_helper_class = ExportButtonHelper
    url_helper_class = ExportAdminURLHelper

    export_view_class = ExportView

    def get_admin_urls_for_registration(self):
        urls = super().get_admin_urls_for_registration()
        urls += (
            url(
                self.url_helper.get_action_url_pattern('export'),
                self.export_view,
                name=self.url_helper.get_action_url_name('export')
            ),
        )

        return urls

    def export_view(self, request):
        kwargs = {'model_admin': self}
        view_class = self.export_view_class
        return view_class.as_view(**kwargs)(request)
```

In `/feedler/wagtail_hooks.py`, create and `register` the `ModelAdmin`:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register

from .admin import ExportModelAdminMixin
from .models import Entry

class EntryModelAdmin(ExportModelAdminMixin, ModelAdmin):
    model = Entry
    # ...
    
modeladmin_register(EntryModelAdmin)
```

With all that setup, you should be able to use `{% include 'modeladmin/includes/button.html' with button=view.button_helper.export_button %}` in the template created above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I did everything according to your instructions, but unfortunately the button did not appear. I hope that I was not mistaken anywhere. In your code, this line was missing:
`from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator` .
Here is my **model:** [github repo](https://github.com/khashashin/public-health-ch/blob/fd2ccf68eb488365a97d6fc49d0e1c8d6f4a5b49/feedler/models/models.py#L57) **template:** [template](https://github.com/khashashin/public-health-ch/blob/fd2ccf68eb488365a97d6fc49d0e1c8d6f4a5b49/modeladmin/feedler/entry/index.html#L1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing import. I've updated the answer. As for the button now showing, I reckon it's because you do not register the new [ModelAdmin](https://github.com/khashashin/public-health-ch/blob/fd2ccf68eb488365a97d6fc49d0e1c8d6f4a5b49/feedler/models/models.py#L166) but instead still register the [old one](https://github.com/khashashin/public-health-ch/blob/fd2ccf68eb488365a97d6fc49d0e1c8d6f4a5b49/feedler/wagtail_hooks.py#L8). Update `EntryModelAdmin` in `wagtail_hooks.py` and make it inherit from `ExportModelAdminMixin`.

Comment: Furthermore, you can probably move all the model admin logic to `wagtail_hooks.py` or `admin.py`. I'll update the answer to show the hierarchy (and update to your model name).

Comment: Great worked example. You've imported `AdminURLHelper` but used `FilteredAdminURLHelper` also the import for reverse is `from django.urls import reverse` since Django 1.10

Comment: Updated. Thanks @Zemogle! I reckon the `FilterableAdminURLHelper` was an intermediary class I had in my project so I replaced it with `AdminURLHelper`.

Comment: What is this last "url" supposed to be? It's throwing an error for me:      def get_admin_urls_for_registration(self):
        urls = super().get_admin_urls_for_registration()
        urls += (
            url(

Comment: It's registering the URL to the export view we created. Your message is cut off though so I can't tell what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out, if you are listing Pages you will need to subclass from PageAdminURLHelper, not from AdminURLHelper (FilterableAdminURLHelper doesn't seem to be a standard implementation).
Otherwise, you will have some strange redirections taking place.