# Adding custom action buttons to Wagtail Admin

Tags: wagtail

In Wagtail, I currently have content which I wish to update based on API calls to another website:

- I have a VideoPage with fields like `url`, `title` and `description`. When adding a VideoPage I'd like to be able to enter just the `url` , click a button, and it'll try to prepopulate the other fields by making API calls (via either the front end or back end)
- I also have a ChannelPage, which VideoPages are children of. I'd ideally like a way to click a button in admin, have my server check whether the channel has new videos, then create new VideoPage children accordingly.

From the above use cases, I believe my problem comes down to this: is it possible to add standalone action buttons to the admin area for a Page which, when clicked, allows the backend to edit fields, create new pages, etc. accordingly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a button to Wagtail Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206693/adding-a-button-to-wagtail-dashboard)

Comment: Probably this posts can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206693/adding-a-button-to-wagtail-dashboard  

https://parbhatpuri.com/add-download-csv-option-in-wagtail-modeladmin.html