# Adding a button to export to a csv/xlsx file on Wagtail Dashboard

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am attempting the solution mentioned in this stack overflow post ([Adding a button to Wagtail Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206693/adding-a-button-to-wagtail-dashboard)) however the solution might be outdated, or at least it doesn't work for me and I'm unsure why.

Goal: Be able to export a object's data to csv

First, the button HTML code had to be slightly adjusted to be formatted correctly like so:

```
{% extends "modeladmin/index.html" %}
{% block header_extra %}
    <div class="right">
        <div class="addbutton" style="margin-left: 2em;">
            {% include "modeladmin/includes/button.html" with button=view.button_helper.export_button %}
            <a href="#" class="button bicolor icon icon-download">My button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ block.super }}{% comment %}Display the original buttons {% endcomment %}
{% endblock %}
```

and then I copied and pasted the views and helper functions:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.helpers import AdminURLHelper, ButtonHelper
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import IndexView


class ExportButtonHelper(ButtonHelper):
    """
    This helper constructs all the necessary attributes to create a button.
    
    There is a lot of boilerplate just for the classnames to be right :(
    """
    
    export_button_classnames = ['icon', 'icon-download']

    def export_button(self, classnames_add=None, classnames_exclude=None):
        if classnames_add is None:
            classnames_add = []
        if classnames_exclude is None:
            classnames_exclude = []

        classnames = self.export_button_classnames + classnames_add
        cn = self.finalise_classname(classnames, classnames_exclude)
        text = _('Export {}'.format(self.verbose_name_plural.title()))

        return {
            'url': self.url_helper.get_action_url('export', query_params=self.request.GET),
            'label': text,
            'classname': cn,
            'title': text,
        }


class ExportAdminURLHelper(AdminURLHelper):
    """
    This helper constructs the different urls.
    
    This is mostly just to overwrite the default behaviour
    which consider any action other than 'create', 'choose_parent' and 'index'
    as `object specific` and will try to add the object PK to the url
    which is not what we want for the `export` option.
    
    In addition, it appends the filters to the action.
    """

    non_object_specific_actions = ('create', 'choose_parent', 'index', 'export')

    def get_action_url(self, action, *args, **kwargs):
        query_params = kwargs.pop('query_params', None)

        url_name = self.get_action_url_name(action)
        if action in self.non_object_specific_actions:
            url = reverse(url_name)
        else:
            url = reverse(url_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

        if query_params:
            url += '?{params}'.format(params=query_params.urlencode())

        return url

    def get_action_url_pattern(self, action):
        if action in self.non_object_specific_actions:
            return self._get_action_url_pattern(action)

        return self._get_object_specific_action_url_pattern(action)
        

class ExportView(IndexView):
    """
    A Class Based View which will generate 
    """
    
    def export_csv(self):
        data = self.queryset.all()
        response = ...
        return response
    
    
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.export_csv()

        
class ExportModelAdminMixin(object):
    """
    A mixin to add to your model admin which hooks the different helpers, the view
    and register the new urls.
    """

    button_helper_class = ExportButtonHelper
    url_helper_class = ExportAdminURLHelper

    export_view_class = ExportView

    def get_admin_urls_for_registration(self):
        urls = super().get_admin_urls_for_registration()
        urls += (
            url(
                self.url_helper.get_action_url_pattern('export'),
                self.export_view,
                name=self.url_helper.get_action_url_name('export')
            ),
        )

        return urls

    def export_view(self, request):
        kwargs = {'model_admin': self}
        view_class = self.export_view_class
        return view_class.as_view(**kwargs)(request)
```

and then I added the ModelAdmin to the hooks. I'm able to see the button however it doesn't function as it's supposed to (exporting the csv). In fact, it does absolutely nothing (the href is # after all) and I feel like I'm missing some steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the same implementation as you.
I guess that you are having problems in the `def export_csv(self)` method
here my implementation

```py
from djqscsv.djqscsv import render_to_csv_response


class ExportView(IndexView):
    model_admin = None

    def export_csv(self) -> dict:
        if (self.model_admin is None) or not hasattr(
            self.model_admin, "csv_export_fields"
        ):
            data = self.queryset.all().values()
        else:
            data = self.queryset.all().values(*self.model_admin.csv_export_fields)
        return render_to_csv_response(data)

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request: HttpRequest, *args: list, **kwargs: dict) -> dict:
        super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.export_csv()
```

`csv_export_fields` can be added to your model admin to specify which fields you want to export

here I am adding the HTML file:

```html
{% extends "modeladmin/index.html" %}

{% block header_extra %}
    {% include 'modeladmin/includes/button.html' with button=view.button_helper.export_button %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

your admin.py

```py
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin, ExportModelAdminMixin): 
    model = MyModel 
    menu_icon = 'tag' 
    menu_order = 200 
    index_template_name = "wagtailadmin/export_csv.html"
    csv_export_fields = [ "field_name","field_name_1", ]
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name'') 
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer unfortunately your implementation doesn't seem to have changed the functionality. I had a very misleading typo in my question, I meant to say that the button doesn't work as intended and that clicking it does absolutely nothing. 

After editing the new ExportView clicking the button still doesn't do anything. I did notice I had to install django-queryset-csv and import the render_to_csv_response to clear up the errors.

Comment: you are welcome, in your code there was not `render_to_csv_response` you just return an empty response and this is what I have written in the code: `return render_to_csv_response(data)` and of course you need to import it to make it work

Comment: Hi ladhari, unfortunately even with your code it the button still does function. Clicking it still does nothing, are you able to confirm that it would work normally? What would your setup look like? I do want to verify whether or not the index.html is properly set up. Is the href="#" the reason why it does nothing? What would I be replacing it with?

Comment: Hi Vice, I was thinking that you made it work, you still can not download the csv file? I am adding my HTML code

Comment: by the way can you copy the code of your model admin? you need to add the class `ExportModelAdminMixin` to your model admin ex: class MyModelAdmin(ExportModelAdminMixin, ModelAdmin):

Comment: ```class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin, ExportModelAdminMixin):```
    ```model = MyAdminModel```
    ```menu_icon = 'tag'```
    ```menu_order = 200```
    ```list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name'')```
    ```search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)```

Comment: I think that you have forgot to add the the template of index view in your model admin: `index_template_name = "wagtailadmin/export_csv.html"`

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much for your help! It now works, however I notice that it doesn't print out a child key of the model. As you can see from my code above, model = MyAdminModel, the children of the parental key of that model isn't printed out to excel, how would I accomplish that? This may warrant a separate post but just in case it would be an easy alteration of 1 or 2 lines I wanted to ask this last request.

Comment: glad to hear that !usually you can specify which fields you want to download using this: csv_export_fields = [
        "field_name","field_name_1",
        
    ]

Comment: Where would that line of code go? I noticed that model_admin is set to none in your ExportView.